# (Moodle) I keep getting raw data when exporting .xlsx file containing HighCharts Images

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, xlsx, moodle

This issue has baffled me, mainly because it makes no sense. I have some custom PHP code that I wrote on top of my LMS system (Moodle) to display some of its collected data in a HighCharts Table. What makes no sense is that I can almost GUARANTEE the code isn't broken because I checked older working versions of it and the same problem occurs. I never ran an update on Moodle in a long time so no known changes could have affected this.

Here are some weird things I found while troubleshooting:

- Only this report is giving this issue.
- Whenever I move this ENTIRE code to another PHP with a different name the issue doesn't occur.

Some more important details:

- Uses the online version of highcharts.js scripts
- The scripts I'm using are:

  "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"
  "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"
  "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"
  "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"
  "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js

Please let me know if you've seen this issue before and what step you took to fix it. Also, I can't share the website this issue is on because the content password locked within my Organization.

[CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE: This is what happens when I click the export button. The URL changes to something long and then outputs this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnZSJ.png)

Comment: At a guess, I would expect that something is outputting to the page (maybe just a space or a newline character), before the binary data of the spreadsheet is output. The initial output would make your browser start showing the page content (having interpreted the page content type as text), so by the time the spreadsheet content arrives, it is too late to save to a file instead.

Comment: I don't think that this issue is related to using the Highcharts library.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel do you have any idea what might cause this. This problem has gotten me completely stumped.